# Stretching towards a vector

Tags: three.js

I am **stumped**.

I've created a line geometry in the shape of a spring, and I'd like to be able to transform this spring such that one end remains fixed in place while the other follows a vector3 position. The object3D.lookAt() method gets it pointing the right way, but I can't figure out a way to *stretch* it to that point.

I figure it'd be a matrix4.makeTransform() but I don't know how to calculate the amounts to scale in each direction. I thought it'd be simply dividing the x, y, and z coordinates of the endpoint of my spring and the target point, but that hasn't worked at all.

Is there a method to do this that I've somehow missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .lookAt call, makes the spring point its own z-axis (hopefully the axis running along the length of the spring! if you've got your mesh set up correctly!)

Once you have it pointed at the target, you need to figure out how far the target is...

using something like

```
distance = new THREE.Vector3().copy(targetPoint).sub( springObject.position).length()
```

Once you know that distance, and assuming you know the default length of the spring model, then it should just be a matter of setting the z axis scale of the spring by the distance/defaultLength.. something like:

```
   springObject.scale.z = defaultLength/distance
```

This could be a little complicated if you are already scaling the spring model by some amount, you'll have to take that into account as well.

Comment: That's done it! In case anyone else is reading this in future, I actually needed to do
```
springObject.scale.z = distance/defaultLength
```
but other than that it's spot on, thanks

Comment: @manthrax - copy takes only one argument, a vector3. Did you mean to use copy?

Comment: Whoa good catch. I fixed the code. Missing a .sub in there. :D Thanks!
@Neil